# reCaptcha badge appears in the lower right only on some pages

Tags: forms, recaptcha, formidable, divi

I am using Formidable Forms with Divi in WordPress 6.2.2. I had a non-Formidable request form in a global section that I replaced with a new formidable form plus a code module containing the reCaptcha Enterprise page script.

All pages that already had that global section show the lower-right reCaptcha badge. Pages that I have added that global section to, like new pages, do not display the badge.

I know it's a quirky problem, but I'm open to suggestions.

Tried adding the section with the form to pages and the badge won't show.

Glenn

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.